# SFTP - Couldn't canonicalize: No such file or directory

Tags: sftp

I use [Core FTP mini-sftp-server] for open sftp server on my windows 10 desktop in easily.

But it happend error like below.

Why error "no such file" when I command "cd .." ?

Thank you.

```
Connected to 
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /
sftp> cd ttt/P0/Debug
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /ttt/P0/Debug/
sftp> dir
obj
sftp> cd obj
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /ttt/P0/Debug/obj/
sftp> dir
sftp> cd ..
Couldn't canonicalize: No such file or directory
sftp>
```

I want to use sftp for transfer files